# prevent click event on toggleClass

Tags: jquery, onclicklistener, toggleclass

I have a click event on an "a" element:

```
<a href="#" class="edit-row">Edit</a>
```

I've attached a click event to this element:

```
$(document).on('click', "a.edit-row", editRow);
```

When clicking the edit button the editRow function is called. This function changes the Edit < a > element:

```
$(this).find("a.edit-row").html("Save").removeClass("edit-row").addClass("save-row").off('click').click(saveRow);
```

This all works fine.

When clicking on "Save" the saveRow function is called. Within this function I want to revert back to the "Edit" button.

This is one of the versions I've used to achieve this:

```
$(this).off('click').html("Edit").toggleClass("save-row").toggleClass("edit-row");
```

I've tried several things other things as well. But what happens, after clicking save it changes to edit but it immediately it changes back to save again.

It looks like the click event from the $(document) part is triggered. However, I can't seem to disable or prevent this click event from triggering when changing the class. It needs to fire once it's clicked again, not on toggleClass().

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're attaching the click handler to the `document` then trying to remove it from `this` which isn't the `document`, it's the clicked `a` tag. From what I understand you need to remove the click handler on `document` and not from `this`. But I really do think you're going way over board with this and it could be simple to just have two handlers and swap the class out.

Comment: Turned out that I was using the wrong selector. The above answer helped me out: I needed to disable the handler on `document` and then it worked. Still I find it strange that using `toggleClass` triggers the click event? Thank Jonny.

Comment: Did some finetuning, the first solution wasn't very satisfying and some of you were making clear that my coding was indeed to difficult. I ended op with replacing all `$(document)` code with simple `$(tableId).find(".edit-row").on('click', editRow)` after initializing the dataTables table. That way using `toggleClass` worked much better and things were much more simple. So simplifying was very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are over complicating things. It looks like all you need is two separate handlers, one for `edit-row` and one for `save-row`. You shouldn't have to remove click handlers at all.

```
$(document).on('click','a.edit-row', function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('edit-row save-row').html('Save');
 //do other stuff in your editRow function
});

$(document).on('click','a.save-row', function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('edit-row save-row').html('Edit'); 
 //do other stuff in your saveRow function
});
```

You can see an example in the fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/cc9he/

Comment: I will proceed with both your comments and the comments of @JonnySooter. The problem is that the buttons are placed within a Datatables generated table and that kind of makes things a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use delegation using the class names to figure out which function to call.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', "a.edit-row", editRow);
    $(document).on('click', "a.save-row", saveRow);
});

function editRow() {
     $(this).html("Save").removeClass("edit-row").addClass("save-row");
}


function saveRow() {
    $(this).html("Edit").removeClass("save-row").addClass("edit-row");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z96pp/

Comment: None of the given answers seem to work. As soon as I click 'save' it switches to 'edit' and switches back immediately You're all pointing in the same direction so I think there's something else messing up things. I'll inform you as soon as I have a solution!

Comment: Hmm, strange. Sure, let us know if there is anything else we are not taking into account.